# I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, and now my /home folders are empty

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, files, home-directory

Did i miss something? Isn't it supposed to keep your /home folders intact when you upgrade?

Is there some way to retrieve what was there?

Comment: It looks like everything is still there, but somehow hiden from me, as if i were logged in as a guest, which i am not, same login and password.

Comment: I'm unsure of what's wrong, but your assumption is correct; an upgrade should save all settings, programs, etc.  It sounds like it thinks you are not the owner for some reason.  Try entering `id` on a commandline; it should show a uid and gid of 1000.  If so, maybe the original ids were changed for some reason.  You can try entering `ls -l` (that's lowercase l, for long) in your home directory and see what it says for owner/group (3rd and 4th columns).  Should have your name, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up terminal
type

```
cd /home/

ls -lFa
```

If something is hidden,  **-lFa** option will display everything.

OR

Check /etc/passwd file by

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

find the line of your user name.
In the same line of your user name, It will show /home/*something* that's the place your previous stuff is located.

Open up nautilus (File Manager)
press

```
CTRL + L
```

type the location you found in /etc/passwd file

Ex

/home/previoisusername

Comment: Awesome. I was wrong, my user name was different. I can't find a way to login under my old user name, but i can just transfer the files over i guess. Thanks guys.

Comment: FYI, you can change password for old user though. 
login with your current user name, open up terminal
`$sudo su`
then 
`#passwd oldusername`